# Ajax JS Functon that returns object is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an AJAX function that returns a JS object. however when i assign a var to the function i get undefined. Debugging in FireBug, everything is fine, except when i try and assign the result to the **var tester**

here is my code...

```
    function AllBidData(HighestBid,MinimumBid,HighestProxyBid) {
        return {
            HighestBid: HighestBid,
            MinimumBid: MinimumBid,
            HighestProxyBid: HighestProxyBid
        };
    }



    function GetAllBidData() {          

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "/VehicleAuction/GetAllBidData",
            data: { AuctionID: AuctionID, UserID: UserID }

        }).done(function (msg) {

            var BidDate = new AllBidData(msg.HighestBid, msg.MinimumBid, msg.HighestProxyBid);
            return BidDate;
        });
    }    

var tester = GetAllBidData(); 
//why is tester is undefined?
```

**UPDATE & SOLUTION** - So this is the way i have solved this problem - using **deferred objects**

```
function GetAllBidData() {          
    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "/VehicleAuction/GetAllBidData",
        data: { AuctionID: AuctionID, UserID: UserID }
    });
}

function AllBidData(data) {
    return {
        HighestBid: data.HighestBid,
        MinimumBid: data.MinimumBid,
        HighestProxyBid: data.HighestProxyBid
    };
}

var tester = null;
tester = GetAllBidData().done(AllBidData);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's asynchronous call. The function executes and returns value before the ajax call happen

```
function GetAllBidData(callback) {          

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "/VehicleAuction/GetAllBidData",
            data: { AuctionID: AuctionID, UserID: UserID }

        }).done(function (msg) {

            var BidDate = new AllBidData(msg.HighestBid, msg.MinimumBid, msg.HighestProxyBid);
            callback(BidDate);
        });
    }    

var tester = GetAllBidData(function(yourValue){
    //do stuff here with yourValue
});
```